# Get image source from html dom element

Tags: php, image, parsing, printing

I am querying image using `getElementsByTagName("img")` and printing it using `image->src` , it does not work. I also tried to use `image->nodeValue` this to does not work.

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');

$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $str);       /*$str contains html output */

$xpath=new DOMXPath($dom); 
$imgfind=$dom->getElementsByTagName('img');  /*finding elements by tag name img*/

foreach($imgfind as $im)
{
    echo $im->src;        /*this doesnt work  */   
    /*echo $im->nodeValue;  and also this doesnt work (i tried both of them             separately ,Neither of them worked)*/

    // echo "<img src=".$im->nodeValue."</img><br>"; //This also did not work
}

/*the image is encolsed within div tags.so i tried to query value of div and print but still image was not printed*/

$printimage=$xpath->query('//div[@class="abc"]'); 
foreach($printimage as $image)
{
    echo $image->src;   //still i could not accomplish my task
}
```

Comment: Emmm.. Could you reduce the length of that title please?

Comment: Did you try `var_dump($imgfind);`

Comment: use `echo $im->getAttribute('src');` instead of `echo $im->src;`

Comment: Also, since you're using `DOM`, there doesn't seem to be necessary to `require('simple_html_dom.php')`.

Comment: @saveATcode i tried using echo $im->getAttribute('src'); it just prints src value of image and not the image.i.e.<img src='a.jpg'> it prints a.jpg as text and it does not print the actual image .

Comment: give the full source path instead of a.jpg in `src`..

Comment: @saveATcode i have already given full source code only and still it did not work ,and from php manual i found getattribute is used to just print the value of attribute only and not value of the html element.

Comment: check the answer i have given now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, use this to display your image:

```
foreach($imgfind as $im)
{
  echo "<img src=".$im->getAttribute('src')."/>"; //use this instead of echo $im->src;
}
```

and it will surely display your image. **Make sure path to the image is correct**.

Comment: ,Thanks the code worked ,there is one small correction i made to ur code ,i.e,a space before ending slash in echo "<img src=".$im->getAttribute('src')." />"; rather than echo "<img src=".$im->getAttribute('src')."/>";(it considers image to be a directory without space   ..otherways its perfectly fine.thanks a lot buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Espero te sirva

```
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  $filename = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0896WB9XD/";
  $html = file_get_contents($filename);

  @$dom->loadHTML($html);

$imgfind=$dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($imgfind as $im)
{
    $ids= $im->getAttribute('id'); 

    if ($ids == 'landingImage') {
        $im2 = $im->getAttribute('src'); 
       echo '<img src="'.$im2.'">';
    }
    else{
        
    }
}
```

para amazon.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and use english.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).