# match and replace str attribute in html

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that contains a few substrings that look like `src="somethin/somethin/the_thing.ext"` and I would like to transform each of them into `src="the_thing.ext"`

```
src="/1/2/3.ext" -> src="3.ext"
src="a/b/c.ext" -> src="c.ext"
src="../d/e.ext" -> src="e.ext"
src="f/g.ext" -> g.ext
src="h.ext" -> h.ext
```

I'm trying to do it in PHP with `preg_replace` or `ereg_replace`
but can figure out how to group the subexpressions. 
My expression consist of zero or more something/ and at the end there is some text (the first something can be preceded with just a /)

```
<?php
$string = '<img src="x.y"  alt="" />&nbsp;<img src="uploads/RTE.jpg"    
alt="" /><br /><img src="../uploads/RTEjpg" alt="" /> <img
src="/fileadmin/CPE.ztc">'
$pattern = '/src=\"(.*?)\"/';
$replacement = 'src="';
echo ereg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

I'm stuck with the pattern and replacemnt, how to write them in regex or extended regex?

Comment: `ereg_replace` is deprecated, and it does not accept regex delimiters. Use `preg_replace`. Here is a [demo](https://ideone.com/JOX0kd) of your fixed code.

Comment: Use a proper html parser to grab the `img` tags, and select their `src` attributes, then simply `explode` the string on `/` and save the last element in the resulting array. Regex could also be used instead of explode, but should not be used for parsing the html, unless you are 100% confident the source doesnt change beyond the contents of the `src` attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lookbehind and lookahead and then `preg_replace`:

```
$string = '<img src="x.y"  alt="" />&nbsp;<img src="uploads/RTE.jpg"
alt="" /><br /><img src="../uploads/RTE.jpg" alt="" /> <img
src="/fileadmin/CPE.ztc">';
$pattern = '/(?<=src=")[^"]+(?<=\/)/';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Output:

```
<img src="x.y" alt="" />&nbsp;<img src="RTE.jpg" alt="" /><br /><img src="RTE.jpg" alt="" /> <img src="CPE.ztc">
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do two things:

1. You will need to use a proper framework to get the content of the `src` tag you are after. Regular expressions on their own is **not** the recommended way. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052158/get-image-source-from-html-dom-element) previous SO question should point you in the right direction.
2. Use an expression such as this: `(\w+\.\w+?$)` (example [here](https://regex101.com/r/hA6nL1/1)) and replace the content of the `src` tag with the content of the 1st regex group. This expression will match one or more letters, numbers or underscores (`\w+`) followed by the period character (`.`), followed by more letters, numbers or underscores and finally the end of the string (`$`).